# Can't run file from storage in termux

Tags: file, directory, termux

I'm using *termux* for programming. I decided to use *acode* for text editor. I setup everything, but at the final, code isn't ran and *bash* gave an error: **Permission denied**. I see this error when I try to run a file from **storage**.

I tried to edit and run files from data, but I want to add these files into my personal directory. How can I run files from storage?
I'm using *Android 11*, *Termux 0.118.0*.